# How to sort an nx3 numpy array by column(s) but it remembers the data in that row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

First off, I'm very new to python and so any tips/help is really appreciated.

Essentially I want an nx3 numpy array to be sorted initially by the second column then by the third but I want all of the data in the row to remain with each other.

Like so:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[20, 2, 4],
              [7, 5, 6],
              [25, 1, 5],
              [2, 2, 3],
              [3, 5, 8],
              [4, 1, 3]])
              ......... (n times)
```

In this array the first column represents the value, the second it's x coordinate and the third its y coordinate. What is the best way to do a descending sort the array by first the x coordinate, then do a descending sort on the y coordinate whilst value still stays assigned to the x and y coordinate?

So after the sort, it looks like this:

```py
a = ([[4, 1, 3],
     [25, 1, 5],
      [2, 2, 3],
     [20, 2, 4],
      [7, 5, 6],
      [3, 5, 8]])
     ......... (n times)
```

As you can see how can it first sort the x coordinate then with sort all the y coordinates which have the same x coordinates. As it first finds all x coordinates of 1 then within that sort the y coordinates. Whilst the value, x and y coordinates all remain on the same row with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to convert it into a pandas dataframe then it's easier to manipulate it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [6, 2, 1], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

print(df)
```

Out

```
 a  b
0  6  4
1  2  5
2  1  6

sorteddf = df.sort_values(by='a')

print(sorteddf)
```

Out

```
a  b
2  1  6
1  2  5
0  6  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'order' parameter: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

```
import numpy as np

dtype = [('x',int),('y',int)]
values = [(1,7),(3,4),(1,4),(1,3)]
a = np.array(values,dtype=dtype)
print(np.sort(a, order=['x','y']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to first sort by y and then sort the result by x, so for equals values of x the final result will be sorted by y.

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[20, 2, 4],
              [7, 5, 6],
              [25, 1, 5],
              [2, 2, 3],
              [3, 5, 8],
              [4, 1, 3]])

a = a[a[:,2].argsort()] # sort according to column 2
a = a[a[:,1].argsort()] # sort according to column 1
```

result

```
a
array([[ 4,  1,  3],
       [25,  1,  5],
       [ 2,  2,  3],
       [20,  2,  4],
       [ 7,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  5,  8]])
```